# selecting items in custom listView repeat

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have custom `listview`

```
    public class MisscallListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SmsClass>
```

This is `viewHolder` :

```
        private static class ViewHolder {
               TextView number , name , date , count , time;
               ImageButton btnCall , btnSendsms , btnDelete;
               ImageView imageIcon;
               CheckBox checkBox;
        }
```

In the `getView` method I try to get the item that clicked by user and put it in an `ArrayList` like this :

```
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    final SmsClass smsClass = getItem(position);

    String nameInside = smsClass.getName();
    final String numInside = smsClass.getNumberInside();

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService( Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        viewHolder.date =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.count = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);
        viewHolder.btnCall = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById( R.id.btn_call );
        viewHolder.btnSendsms = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById( R.id.btn_sms);
        viewHolder.imageIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById( R.id.checkBox);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();




    viewHolder.name.setText( //text );

    viewHolder.date.setText( //text );
    viewHolder.number.setText( //text );
    viewHolder.count.setText( //text );



    viewHolder.btnSendsms.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                TextView selected = (TextView) MainActivity.smsList.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.name);
                clicked_number = selected.getText().toString();

                openSMS( numInside);
            }
            catch (Exception e){}
        }
    } );

    viewHolder.btnCall.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                TextView selected = (TextView) MainActivity.smsList.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.name);
                clicked_number = selected.getText().toString();

                dialContactPhone(numInside);
            }
            catch (Exception e){}
        }

    } );


    final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;
    final View finalConvertView = convertView;
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (finalViewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
                selected.add( smsClass );

            } else {

                for(int i = 0 ; i < selected.size() ; i++){
                    if(selected.get( i ).getId() == smsClass.getId())
                        selected.remove( i );
                }
            }
        }

    } );


    if(isEnd == true) {

        for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.smsList.getCount(); i++) {

            Log.i( "ujkac" , "count:    " + i );
            viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked( false );
        }
    }


    return convertView;

}
```

The `smsClass` above is:

```
    final SmsClass smsClass = getItem(position);
```

The problem is when I select the first row of the list(just first item) and make it checked then the fifth item checked too and tenth item and ... 
help, please.

Comment: show onBindViewHolder() method code

Comment: @ Rahul Khurana  I don't have this method

Comment: ok. put the whole **getView** method code

Comment: @ Rahul Khurana ok, I edit the question

Comment: You need to store the CheckBox state of the button in the list using **setOnCheckedChangeListener** method. And when **getView()** method is called set the CheckBox checked/unchecked state according to the position

Comment: @ Rahul Khurana thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Viewholder Pattern! See [RecyclerView with ViewHolder pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652166/recyclerview-with-viewholder-pattern)
Its easy and effective way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

During recreation of view's layout in case when the layout exists You restore values such as:

```
viewHolder.name.setText( //text );
viewHolder.date.setText( //text );
viewHolder.number.setText( //text );
viewHolder.count.setText( //text );
```

But You are not restoring state for `checkbox`. There is a missing line for that:

```
viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(checkedArray[position];
```

That was for restoring.

There is also a missing part of code where You save checkboxes states according to view's position (I assume Your list is static).

```
viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //...

        checkedArray[position] = !checkBox.isChecked();

        //...
    }

});
```

I would like point one thing. If You want listen to checkbox's states, You should use [setOnCheckedChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8386876/619673).